# Maven pom.xml set encoding for plugin does not work

Tags: java, xml, maven, maven-surefire-plugin

I have pom.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <directory>target</directory>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>target/classes</outputDirectory>
        <finalName>AUTOMATION-01</finalName>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java/com/my/tests</testSourceDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>target/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                    <groups>com.my.testgroups.AutoTestsGroup</groups>
                    <argLine>-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>


    <reporting>
        <outputDirectory>target/site</outputDirectory>
    </reporting>

    <profiles>

        <profile>
            <id>release-profile</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I use maven-surefire-plugin to generate reports by have reports like

```
 РџРѕР»СѓС‡Р°РµРј РёРјСЏ С„Р°Р№Р»Р° СЃ С‚РµСЃС‚РєРµР№СЃРѕРј Рё РёРјСЏ СЃР°РјРѕРіРѕ С‚РµСЃС‚РєРµР№СЃР°
2015-10-12 11:30:57 INFO  - Р’С‹РїРѕР»РЅСЏРµС‚СЃСЏ С„Р°Р№Р» С‚РµСЃС‚РєРµР№СЃ : case1_125_multidrive, СЃ РёРјРµРЅРµРј РєРµР№СЃР°: РЎРѕР±СЃС‚РІРµРЅРЅРёРє_СЂР°РІРЅРѕ_РЎС‚СЂР°С…РѕРІР°С‚РµР»СЊ_РњРѕСЃРєРІР°-РІРѕР·СЂР°СЃС‚_Р±РѕР»СЊС€Рµ_18-125Р»СЃ_РјСѓР»СЊС‚РёРґСЂР°Р№РІ
2015-10-12 11:30:57 INFO  - ########## РЎРѕР·РґР°РµРј РІР»Р°РґРµР»СЊС†Р° РўРЎ #########
2015-10-12 11:30:57 INFO  - Р¤Р°РјРёР»РёСЏ Р’РёС‚СЂСЏРє
2015-10-12 11:30:57 INFO  - Р�РјСЏ РђРіР°Рї
2015-10-12 11:30:57 INFO  - РћС‚С‡РµСЃС‚РІРѕ РђР»РµРєСЃРµРµРІРёС‡
2015-10-12 11:30:57 INFO  - Р“РµРЅРµСЂРёСЂСѓРµРј РґР°С‚Сѓ СЂРѕР¶РґРµРЅРёСЏ РІ СЃРѕРѕС‚РІРµС‚СЃС‚РІРёРё СЃ СѓСЃР»РѕРІРёРµРј: РІРѕР·СЂР°СЃС‚_Р±РѕР»СЊС€Рµ_18
2015-10-12 11:30:57 INFO  - Р”Р°С‚Р° СЂРѕР¶РґРµРЅРёСЏ: 1967-01-16
2015-10-12 11:30:57 INFO  - Р’РѕРґРёС‚РµР»СЊСЃРєРёР№ СЃС‚Р°Р¶ РЅРµ Р±СѓРґРµС‚ СЃРіРµРЅРµСЂРёСЂРѕРІР°РЅ, РјСѓР»СЊС‚РёРґСЂР°Р№РІ
2015-10-12 11:30:57 INFO  - ######### Starting create user request on UAT env. ########
2015-10-12 11:30:57 INFO  - РЎРѕР·РґР°РЅ РІР»Р°РґРµР»РµС† РўРЎ СЃ publicID: su:2086
2015-10-12 11:30:59 INFO  - РљР°СЃРєРѕ РєРІРѕС‚Р° СЃС‚РѕРёРјРѕСЃС‚СЊ null
2015-10-12 11:30:59 INFO  - РћСЃР°РіРѕ РєРІРѕС‚Р° СЃС‚РѕРёРјРѕСЃС‚СЊ null
```

I did set encoding for this plugin but it doesnot work at all. 
I try to run maven on Jenkins and use JUnit Jenkins plugin for reports
Please help to understand what is the problem

Answer (score 1):

*Use Jenkins Maven Build* enter as goal: `mvn clean package`

*Use [Jenkins M2 Release Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin)* to create a new release of your library. This will deploy the create jar(s) to you central Maven repository, like [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/downloads/) or [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/open-source/).

For the report encoding use by [surefire encoding](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#encoding) set the property `project.reporting.outputEncoding`:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

There are several things in the `pom.xml` that can be removed, as these are `pom.xml` defaults. Like:

- Remove the entry `packaging` with value `jar`, as it is default.
- Remove `sourceDirectory` with value `src/main/java` as it is the default
- Remove `outputDirectory` wit value `target/classes` as it is the default
- Remove `testOutputDirectory` with value `target/test-classes` as it is the default
- Remove `resources/resource/directory` with the value `src/main/resources` as it is the default
- Question: Is the `testSourceDirectory` value really `src/test/java/com/my/tests` ? Looks like it includes a part of the package name. It should just contain the path to the directory, where the pacakge name starts. Exact the same as for the `sourceDirectory`, with the value `src/main/java`. A more logical value would be `src/test/java`, which is the default, so would not need to set it.
- Remove the `reporting` entries, all are default. And in case you like to change the output location set the property `project.reporting.outputDirectory` (See [Site Output Directory](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/site-mojo.html#outputDirectory))
- Remove the `finalName`, as makes it more unclear then clearer. The default will be the artifact id, so here `automation`.

`<reporting>
        <outputDirectory>target/site</outputDirectory>
    </reporting>`

The `pom.xml` would probably look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.my</groupId>
    <artifactId>automation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java/com/my/tests</testSourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <updateReleaseInfo>true</updateReleaseInfo>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>methods</parallel>
                    <threadCount>10</threadCount>
                    <groups>com.my.testgroups.AutoTestsGroup</groups>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>release-profile</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: The `<inherited>true</inherited>` can also be removed. Furthermore `<testSourceDirectory>..</testSourceDirectory>` and `<finalName>..</finalName>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2</version>
    <configuration>
      <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

And:

```
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
```